# Adding custom property to the rectangle class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to add a custom property to the Rectangle class. I tried to subclass the Rectangle class but it didn't work. Is there a way to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inherit from `System.Drawing.Rectangle`, because it's not a class, it's a `struct`. What you can do is to create your own class (or `struct`) that wraps `Rectangle`, something like:

```
class MyRectangle
{
    public Rectangle ActualRectangle { get; set; }
    public SomeType AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could hide the `Rectangle` and provide methods and properties that mirror those of `Rectangle` that call them.

Answer (score 3):

You can not extend Rectangle as it's a value type. 
In my opinion you have 2 choices:

1. Extension method. Something like this:

   ```
   public static class Extensions
   {
       static object myporpertyvalue = null;
       public static void SetMyProperty(this Rectangle rect, object value) 
       {
           myporpertyvalue = value;
       }

       public static object GetMyProperty(this Rectangle rect) 
       {
          return myporpertyvalue ;
       }
   }
   ```

   The type of a property is unknown to me so I put it like an `object`, you need to substitute it with the type you need, naturally.
2. Wrap Rectangle into your custom class.

Comment: Using extension method this way probably won't work, because I think having one value for each `rectangle` is not enough.

Comment: Yes, but we can add another extension methods for them Set/Get my property1,..2,..3 whatever... We can use different parameters. An object type in the code is purely pseudocode, as I wrote.

Comment: I guess you don't understand me. How would I use your extension method approach if I have two rectangles and I want to have different values of `MyProperty` for each of them?

Comment: @svick: ok, now I got it. It's true, this is a design limitation. If you need that kind of approach, you have to go for second option (wrap).

Comment: @svick
Has he not add Set and Get xtension methods. So that you can do

rectobj1.Set("blah")
and 
rectObj2.Set("bleh")

Comment: @zenwalker, you can, but after you run both your lines, both `rectobj1.GetMyProperty()` and `rectobj2.GetMyProperty()` will return `"bleh"`.

Comment: @zenwalker: it will return the same value. May be it's possible to think about some workarround for this solution, lie creating a map table between object and value, but honeslty it's a huge overcode in my opinion, it's better just to wrap it.

Comment: @Tigran
Just check the code i wrote just now (pastebin link). It did work any way.

Comment: @zenwalker, it says “Unknown Paste ID!”.

Comment: @zenwalker, yeah, it works this way. But try rearranging the code to: `h1.SetValue("2"); h2.SetValue("5"); Console.WriteLine(h1.GetValue()); Console.WriteLine(h2.GetValue());`