# Is there a way to add additional values to the rectangle struct?

Tags: c#, rectangles

I want to add additional values to a rectangle. Like a "Name" string for example.

Something like this:

```
Rectangle MyRectangle = new Rectangle(Y, X, Width, Height, Name)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use inheritance, create a class MyRectangle: Rectangle and add the properties, try it, if you have problems, then ask

Comment: Have you tried modifying the existing struct like you propose, or tried extending the `Rectangle` struct with your own struct?  What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding custom property to the rectangle class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294971/adding-custom-property-to-the-rectangle-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two overload constructor function in [Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

```
public Rectangle(Point location, Size size);
public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

But there isn't a constructor function parameter `new Rectangle([int], [int], [int], [int], [string])` in `Rectangle` class.

You can try to use composite `public Rectangle rect { get; set; }` property in the class.

Then use constructor function to set `Rectangle` object and `Name`

```
public class CustomerRectangle 
{
    public Rectangle Rect { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CustomerRectangle(int llx, int lly, int urx, int ury,string name) 
    {
        Rect = new Rectangle(llx, lly, urx, ury);
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

then you can use

```
CustomerRectangle  MyRectangle = new CustomerRectangle (Y, X, Width, Height, Name);

//MyRectangle.Name; use Name property 
//MyRectangle.Rect; use Rectangle
```

Comment: I think you can't inherit from a structure.See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222935/why-dont-structs-support-inheritance

Comment: `System.Drawing.Rectangle` is a **structure**, not a **class**. You can use composition and define a new struct (or class, as desired) with the additional members you want, but it won't be polymorphic with `System.Drawing.Rectangle`, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes you are right I lost it. I edit my answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using a constructor from the System.Drawing namespace:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=netframework-4.7.2

It is not possible to add an extra field to that structure. What you can do is create your own class or structure which does contain more .

```
public class NamedRectangle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y { get; set; }

    public double Width { get; set; }

    public double Height { get; set; }

    public NamedRectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make that a struct - it doesn't need to be a class.  Or, as someone else mentioned, you could simply create a struct or class that composes a Rectangle and a string and mimic the existing Rectangular signature and behavior (but, it wouldn't be a Rectangle)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen others have contributed good examples, but in case of `Cannot inherit from sealed type` error, following example might help you:

```
public class myRectangle
{

    private Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle();
    private string name;

    public myRectangle Rectangle(Int32 Y, Int32 X, Int32 Height, Int32 Width, string name )
    {
       newRectangle.Y = Y;
       newRectangle.X = X;
       newRectangle.Height = Height;
       newRectangle.Width = Width;
       this.name = name;

       return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!